# Разница в значениях

Tags: лингвистика

Интуитивно я понимаю разницу, но как сформулировать словами, в чем разница между словами "спой-воспой", "встать-восстань" и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ты воспой, ты воспой в саду, соловейко..." Это строчка из русской народной песни. Здесь явное значение глагола ВОСПОЙ - начни петь, спой (ср.:вспой). Мне кажется, старославянский элемент вос- изменился на вс-. Вероятно, со временем утратился первый глухой согласный в приставке вс-, и получилось спой.

Теперь о глаголах "встать - восстать". Вспомним "Пророка" Пушкина: "Восстань (=встань), пророк, и виждь, и внемли..." Поэт использует в стихотворении   "...как минимум 30 слов с приметами старославянизмов. Среди них слова с приставками воз- и вос- ("воззвал" и "восстань") *По статье Николенковой Н.В. "Старославянский язык"*

ВОССТАТЬ. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. Преф. производное от стати > стать. Значение "восстать" < "встать", "подняться".Шанский Н.М. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов/ Н.М. Шанский, Т.А. Боброва. — 7-е изд., стереотип. — М.: Дрофа, 2004. — 398, [2] с.

Итак, "спой - воспой" и "встать - восстать"  могут восприниматься  словами с одинаковым значением. Но в современном русском языке слова ВОСПЕВАТЬ и ВОССТАВАТЬ употребляются в значении "восхвалять" и "подыматься противу кого, делаться противником чего; возмущаться, идти против властей (*Даль*)" соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

*Спеть* - это значит исполнить какой-то мотив, какую-то песню. *Воспевать* - это восхвалять (даже не обязательно в песенной форме) что-нибудь/кого-нибудь.

---

*Встать* - просто действие смены положения в пространстве, а *восстать* - это значит воспрянуть, как, например, Феникс восстал из пепла, либо поднять на борьбу с чем-нибудь, например: "Крестьяне восстали против королей".